# Write several distributed arrays with MPI IO

Tags: fortran, mpi, fortran90, mpi-io

I am rewriting a numerical simulation code that is parallelized using MPI in one direction. 
So far, the arrays containing the data were saved by the master MPI process, which implied transferring the data from all MPI processes to one and allocate huge arrays to store the whole thing. It is not very efficient nor classy, and is a problem for large resolutions.

I am therefore trying to use MPI-IO to write directly the file from the distributed arrays. One of the constraint I have is that the written file needs to respect the fortran "unformatted" format (i.e. 4 bytes integer before and after each field indicating its size).

I wrote a simple test program, that works when I write only one distributed array to the file. However, when I write several arrays, the total size of the file is wrong and when comparing to the equivalent fortran 'unformatted' file, the files are different.

Here is the sample code :

```
module arrays_dim
   implicit none
   INTEGER,        PARAMETER :: dp   = kind(0.d0) 
   integer,        parameter :: imax = 500 
   integer,        parameter :: jmax = 50 
   integer,        parameter :: kmax = 10 
end module arrays_dim
module mpi_vars
   use mpi 
   implicit none
   integer, save          :: ierr, myID, numprocs
   integer, save          :: i_start, i_end, i_mean, i_loc
   integer, save          :: subArray, fileH
   integer(MPI_OFFSET_KIND), save   :: offset, currPos
end module mpi_vars

program test
   use mpi 
   use arrays_dim
   use mpi_vars
   real(dp), dimension(0:imax,0:jmax+1,0:kmax+1) :: v, w
   real(dp), dimension(:,:,:), allocatable       :: v_loc, w_loc
   integer                                       :: i, j, k

   call MPI_INIT(ierr) 
   call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myID, ierr) 
   call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, numprocs, ierr) 

   i_mean = (imax+1)/numprocs
   i_start = myID*i_mean
   i_end   = i_start+i_mean-1
   if(i_mean*numprocs<imax+1) then 
    if(myID == numprocs-1) i_end = imax
   endif
   i_loc = i_end - i_start + 1
   allocate(v_loc(i_start:i_end,0:jmax+1,0:kmax+1))
   allocate(w_loc(i_start:i_end,0:jmax+1,0:kmax+1))

   print*, 'I am:', myID, i_start, i_end, i_loc
   do k=0,kmax+1
      do j=0,jmax+1
         do i=0,imax
            v(i,j,k) = i+j+k
            w(i,j,k) = i*j*k
         enddo
      enddo
   enddo

   if(myID==0) then 
       open(10,form='unformatted')
       write(10) v
       !write(10) w
       close(10)
   endif

   do k=0,kmax+1
      do j=0,jmax+1
         do i=i_start,i_end
            v_loc(i,j,k) = i+j+k
            w_loc(i,j,k) = i*j*k
         enddo
      enddo
   enddo

   call MPI_Type_create_subarray (3, [imax+1, jmax+2, kmax+2], [i_loc, jmax+2, kmax+2], &
                                     [i_start, 0, 0], &
                                    MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, subArray,  ierr)
   call MPI_Type_commit(subArray, ierr)
   call MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 'mpi.dat',         &
                     MPI_MODE_WRONLY + MPI_MODE_CREATE + MPI_MODE_APPEND, &
                     MPI_INFO_NULL, fileH, ierr )   


   call saveMPI(v_loc, (i_loc)*(jmax+2)*(kmax+2))
   !call saveMPI(w_loc, (i_loc)*(jmax+2)*(kmax+2))

   call MPI_File_close(fileH, ierr)      

   deallocate(v_loc,w_loc)
   call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr) 
end program test
!
subroutine saveMPI(array, n)
   use mpi
   use arrays_dim
   use mpi_vars

   implicit none
   real(dp), dimension(n) :: array
   integer                   :: n

   offset = (imax+1)*(jmax+2)*(kmax+2)*8
   if(myID==0) then
     call MPI_File_seek(fileH, int(0,MPI_OFFSET_KIND), MPI_SEEK_CUR, ierr)
     call MPI_File_write(fileH, [(imax+1)*(jmax+2)*(kmax+2)*8], 1, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)
     call MPI_File_seek(fileH, offset, MPI_SEEK_CUR, ierr)
     call MPI_File_write(fileH, [(imax+1)*(jmax+2)*(kmax+2)*8], 1, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)
   endif 
   call MPI_File_set_view(fileH, int(4,MPI_OFFSET_KIND), MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, subArray, 'native', MPI_INFO_NULL, ierr)
   call MPI_File_write_all(fileH, array, (i_loc)*(jmax+2)*(kmax+2), MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)  
end subroutine saveMPI
```

when the lines `!write(10) w` and `!call saveMPI(w_loc, (i_loc)*(jmax+2)*(kmax+2))` are commented (i.e. I only write the v array), the code is working fine :

```
mpif90.openmpi -O3 -o prog main.f90
mpirun.openmpi -np 4 ./prog
cmp mpi.dat fort.10
```

cmp does not generate an output, so the files are identical. 
If however I uncomment these lines, then the resulting files (mpi.dat and fort.10) are different. I am sure that the problem lies in the way I define the offset I use to write the data at the right position on the file, but I do not know how to indicate to the second call of saveMPI that the initial position should be the end of the file. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the first call to `saveMPI` is working as you expect it to. Everything get messed up from the second call up. Here are few indications of what is happening:

- `MPI_File_set_view` resets the independent file pointers and the shared file pointer to zero. See [MPI_File_set_view](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_File_set_view.3.php) for more details. So you are actually overwriting `v` data with `w` data when you call `MPI_File_set_view` in `saveMPI`.
- with [`MPI_File_write`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_File_write.3.php), the data is written into those parts of the file specified by the current view. This mean that the way you are adding the size information into the file, is not really compatible with the view previously set for `v`.
- calling `MPI_File_seek` with `MPI_SEEK_CUR` set the position relative to the current position of the individual pointer. So, for the second call, it is relative to the individual pointer of process `0`

I do not use parallel IO that much, so I can not help more that this unless I step into the docs, which I do not have time to. The hint I can give is to:

- add an additional parameter to `saveMPI` that will contain the absolute displacement of the data to write; this can be an `[in out]` arg. For the first call, it will be zero and for subsequent calls, it will be the size of all data already written to file, including the size information. It can be updated in `saveMPI`.
- before writing the size information (by process 0) call `MPI_File_set_view` to reset the view to linear byte stream as originally given by `MPI_File_open`. This can be done by setting the `etype` and `filetype` to both `MPI_BYTE` in calling `MPI_File_set_view`. look into the [doc of `MPI_File_open`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_File_open.3.php) for more information. You will then have to calls to `MPI_File_set_view` in `saveMPI`.

Your `saveMPI` subroutine could look like

```
subroutine saveMPI(array, n, disp)
    use mpi
    use arrays_dim
    use mpi_vars

    implicit none
    real(dp), dimension(n) :: array
    integer                   :: n, disp

    offset = (imax+1)*(jmax+2)*(kmax+2)*8
    call MPI_File_set_view(fileH, int(disp,MPI_OFFSET_KIND), MPI_BYTE, MPI_BYTE, 'native', MPI_INFO_NULL, ierr)
    if(myID==0) then
        call MPI_File_seek(fileH, int(0,MPI_OFFSET_KIND), MPI_SEEK_END, ierr)
        call MPI_File_write(fileH, [(imax+1)*(jmax+2)*(kmax+2)*8], 1, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)
        call MPI_File_seek(fileH, int(offset,MPI_OFFSET_KIND), MPI_SEEK_CUR, ierr)
        call MPI_File_write(fileH, [(imax+1)*(jmax+2)*(kmax+2)*8], 1, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)
    endif
    call MPI_File_set_view(fileH, int(disp+4,MPI_OFFSET_KIND), MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, subArray, 'native', MPI_INFO_NULL, ierr)
    call MPI_File_write_all(fileH, array, (i_loc)*(jmax+2)*(kmax+2), MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)
    disp = disp+offset+8
end subroutine saveMPI
```

and called like:

```
disp = 0
call saveMPI(v_loc, (i_loc)*(jmax+2)*(kmax+2), disp)
call saveMPI(w_loc, (i_loc)*(jmax+2)*(kmax+2), disp)
```

Finally, make sure that you delete the file between two calls because you are using `MPI_MODE_APPEND`.